# Updating code to use Apache HTTPClient 4.5 instead of Common 3.1

Tags: java, apache

I have a program I am trying to upgrade to the latest versions of Apache HTTP client and the code I am having issues with is:

```
private HttpConnectionManager simpleHttpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager(); 

protected HttpConnectionManager getSimpleHttpConnectionManager() {
    return simpleHttpConnection

request = new HttpClientWebRequest(this.simpleHttpConnectionManager);
```

I know that httpclient 4.5 uses BasicHttpConnetionManager and PoolingHttpConnectionManager. I just don't know how to rewrite these lines of code so that they properly use these resources.

This is what I have fixed so far based on somethings I have found in the apache documentation:

```
private HttpClientConnectionManager simpleHttpConnectionManager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager();

protected HttpClientConnectionManager getSimpleHttpConnectionManager() {
    return simpleHttpConnectionManager;
}
```

However, the last line:

```
request = new HttpClientWebRequest(this.simpleHttpConnectionManager);
```